# Object has no attribute ('Miles' object has no attribute 'miles_to_convert')

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to create a basic GUI program with tkinter module.

Here is my main.py code and my miles.py class code:

Main.py

```
from tkinter import *
import Miles


root = Tk()
root.title("Convertitore di miglia in chilometri")
root.configure(height=500, width=500, padx=40, pady=40)

# Creating the entry box
# Nota bene. Per poter fare in modo che otteniamo quanto immagazzinato da Entry dobbiamo per forza avere un bottone
miles_entry = Miles.Miles()
miles_entry.grid(column=2, row=0)

# Creating a button
convert_button = Button(text="Convert", command=miles_entry.on_button_click)
convert_button.grid(column=3, row=0)

# Creating the Labels
equal_label = Label(text="Is equal to:")
equal_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

miles_label = Label(text="miles")
miles_label.grid(column=3, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

And this is my class code:

```
import tkinter


class Miles(tkinter.Entry):
    def __int__(self):
        super().__int__()
        self.miles_to_convert = 0
        self.converted_miles = 0

    def on_button_click(self):
        print(self.miles_to_convert)
```

This is the error I receive and I really can't figure out why...

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ic3b3rg/Dropbox/IT_Lectures/Python/100_Days_of_Code/Day26#PROJECT#16.11.2023#Miles_to_kilometers_converter/Miles.py", line 11, in on_button_click
    print(self.miles_to_convert)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Miles' object has no attribute 'miles_to_convert'
```

Could you please help me? Thank you in advance for your time.

I just want to print the value of self.miles_to_convert on the screen when the button is clicked.

Comment: You have a typo: `__int__`, should be `__init__`. That's why the attributes aren't being set.

Answer (score -1):

```
def __int__
```

Should probably be

```
def __init__
```